# Extracting the Latest Available Year Data

Tags: r, dplyr, time-series, na

I have a fairly large annual dataset in long format and with very large amount of missing values. I am trying to extract the data points for each column for the latest available year.

**Input:**

| ID | Year | x | y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2017 | 1 | NA |
| 1 | 2018 | NA | NA |
| 1 | 2019 | 3 | NA |
| 1 | 2020 | NA | c |

```
data.frame(ID=c(1,1,1,1),
           Year =c(2017, 2018, 2019, 2020),
           x=c(1, NA, 3, NA),
           y=c(NA, NA, NA, "c")
)
```

**Output**:

| ID | x | y |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | c |

```
data.frame(ID=1,
           x=3,
           y="c"
           )
```

Many thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** Assuming the rows are sorted by year within ID which is the case in the question's example -- if not sorted then sort it first using `arrange(ID, Year)` -- remove `Year`, group by `ID`, fill in each remaining column and take the last row of the group.

```
library(dplyr, exclude = c("lag", "filter"))
library(tidyr)

DF %>%
  select(-Year) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  fill %>%
  slice_tail %>%
  ungroup
```

giving:

```
# A tibble: 1 x 3
     ID     x y    
  <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
1     1     3 c
```

**2)** `na.locf0` from zoo would also work and gives the same result.

```
library(dplyr, exclude = c("lag", "filter"))
library(zoo)

DF %>%
  select(-Year) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(across(.fns = na.locf0)) %>%
  slice_tail %>%
  ungroup
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)    

dfx %>%
  pivot_longer(-c(ID, Year),
               values_transform = list(value = as.character)) %>% 
  na.omit() %>% 
  group_by(ID, name) %>% 
  filter(Year == max(Year)) %>% 
  dplyr::select(-Year) %>% 
  pivot_wider(values_from = value, names_from = name) 

# # A tibble: 1 x 3
# ID x     y    
# <dbl> <chr> <chr>
#   1     1 3     c
```

Comment: Thanks so much, this works perfectly but the below solution is faster as pivot_wider slows it down (I have about 1.5 rows)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to address a few things to your question to generate an appropriate response.

- Separate the logic of the question into a [Reprex](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). The question
  is a little unclear in how you want to get your output without
  selecting them manually.
- Show/explain ways that you have attempted the problem as well so
  people don't waste their time or feel like you haven't tried. From
  what you have there i'll give it a go to see if anything helps you.

```
df <- data.frame(ID=c(1,1,1,1),
           Year =c(2017, 2018, 2019, 2020),
           x=c(1, NA, 3, NA),
           y=c(NA, NA, NA, "c")
)
# Remove year like in example?
df <- df %>% 
    select(., -Year) %>%
    filter(, !is.na(y))

# Get values you want?
> df.x <- df %>% 
    select(x) %>%
    na.omit() %>%
    as.double()
# Put together
df[2] <- df.x
```

Comment: sorry for not being clear, this is my first ever stackoverflow post!

Comment: No worries, it takes time before a good post is written, im not the best either...please accept the answer that you prefer to use with the green check mark that helps users know the answer that best solved the question asked. :)